# When a finite local ring $R$ has $-1$ as a square in $R^\times$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, finite-rings

> Let $R$ be a finite local ring with maximal ideal $M$ such that $|R|/|M|\equiv 1\pmod{4}$. Then $-1$ is a square in $R^\times$ (that is, there exists $u\in R^\times$ such that $u^2=-1$) if and only if $-1$ is a square in $(R/M)^\times$. Is this correct?

I know that it is valid for $\mathbb{Z}_{p^\alpha}$ with $p$ odd prime. Is it correct for other cases?

Comment: Are you assuming that $R$ is finite?

Comment: Yes, $R$ is assumed to be finite. I added this in my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's correct!

$R^{\times}\to (R/M)^{\times}$ is a surjective group morphism whose kernel is $1+M$, hence $$R^{\times}/(1+M)\simeq (R/M)^{\times}.$$

If $-1$ is a square in $(R/M)^{\times}$, then there is $a\in R^{\times}$ such that $-a^2\in 1+M$. But $1+M=(1+M)^2$: if $|R|=p^t$, then note that $|1+M|=|M|$, and the last one is also a power of $p$ which is an odd prime. Thus $-a^2\in(1+M)^2$, and therefore there is $b\in 1+M$ such that $-a^2=b^2$, equivalently $-1=(ba^{-1})^2$.

*Remark.* In fact, $1+M$ is the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $R^{\times}$, and we have $$R^{\times}\simeq (R/M)^{\times}\times(1+M).$$

Answer (score 1):

No the completeness of the $p$-adics is important. 
For example let $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ be the localization of$\mathbb{Z}$ at $p$, ie all $\frac{a}{b}$ with $p\nmid b$.

Then $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/p\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=
\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and $-1$ is a root here but clearly not in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.

Comment: All: Observe that this answer was posted before the OP specified the ring to be finite.

Comment: If you knew about `\nmid` but don't want to use it, then I apologize. My experience suggests that relatively few know, and come up with substitutes. IMO using it makes spacing look better and such.